# Unable to create shader program OpenGL LWJGL3

Tags: java, c++, opengl, lwjgl

I am unable to create a shader program to bind to the program id of openGL.
my ShaderProgram class looks as follows:

```
public abstract class ShaderProgram {

private int programID;
private int vertexShaderID;
private int fragmentShaderID;

public ShaderProgram(String vertexFile, String fragmentFile) {                  // Constructor takes the file names for both shaders and loads them into memory
                                                                                // --- Vertex shader does points in 3d space --- fragment shader does colour ---



    if (programID == -1) {                                                      // Error checking for shader program
        programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    }
    if (programID == 0) {
        System.out.println("Could not create shader program");
        System.exit(-1);
    }       

    vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile, GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);                             // Bind shader to programID
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    bindAttributes();
    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
    GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
}

protected abstract void bindAttributes();

protected void bindAttribute(String variableName, int attribute) {              // Takes vao to bind to vertex shader
    GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, attribute, variableName);

}

public void start() {                                                           // Start shader program bound to programID
    GL20.glUseProgram(programID);
}

public void stop() {                                                            // Stop shader program
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
}

public void cleanUp() {                                                         // Unbind shaderID's and delete program from memory
    stop();
    GL20.glDetachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDetachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderID);
    GL20.glDeleteProgram(programID);
}

private int loadShader(String file, int type) {                                 // Read shader file input by filename and shader type
                                                                                //      and store it in a string buffer
    StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();

    InputStream in = Class.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String line;
    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            shaderSource.append(line).append("//\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Could not Load Shader File");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, shaderSource);                            // Creates shader by file and loads it into a new id
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);

    if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {             // Get gl compile status of shader

        System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 1000));                // In case of error, force close and print what went wrong
        System.err.println("Could not compile shader!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    return shaderID;

}

}
```

it is returning with a java heap error as follows:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxFwt.png)

I have attached a link to my github repository for all of the accompanying code.  I believe it is a mishandle with glfw.  All engine files are in the boundary package in renderEngine.  Thanks in advance!
[GitHub KR0N05](https://github.com/Krono5/22ndLife/tree/dev/src/boundary)

Comment: Do you have a valid OpenGL context when you create the shader? You should also decide what you are using desktop opengl or opengl-es and adjust your tags accordingly.

Comment: I am new to openGL so I apologize for my ignorance.  I believe that I do make the opengl context in the display manager in the display manager on init().  However, I might be doing this incorrectly. Any suggestion would be appreciated.  Thank you for the suggestion @BDL!

Comment: I have solved the problem.  @BDL was correct, I was not loading the context in render.prepare before I called the shader create.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. @BDL was correct, I was not loading the context in render.prepare before I called the shader create. Thanks!